Effect of high SPS under low SNR
I want to ask a question about symbol synchronization in demodulation process. As far as I understand, symbol synchronization block consists of three main components: time error detector, interpolator controller and interpolator. Optimal sample point is selected at the output of the interpolator. How does sample per symbol affect demodulation performance under low signal-to-noise ratio environment?
Let say I do have two setup to demodulate a signal. First setup receive signal with 4 SPS and use interpolator block as usual demodulator. Second setup receive the same signal with 400 SPS and doesn't use interpolator block since it has enough samples to select from (still has interpolator controller). Do they have any performance difference (in terms of error probability) from each other for linear (PSK, QAM) or nonlinear (FSK) modulations?

Let me simplify the question as there can be many secondary effects based on implementation details between the two approaches suggested.
If we ask if there is any difference in sampling four samples per symbol versus 400 samples per symbol in terms of the SNR in each symbol represented by those samples, the answer is no. This assumes the waveform prior to sampling has been properly filtered to meet the Nyquist requirement to avoid aliasing, and any subsequent processing to reduced the sampling rate further will also be properly filtered prior to such decimation.
Sampling at a higher rate comes at the cost of more digital processing (and associated power dissipation in that portion of the design) but simplifies the analog filtering that would occur prior to the A/D converter. See my answer to DSP.SE #51088 showing the impact on pulse shaping filter performance given same filter complexity when choosing between 2 samples per symbol and 10 samples per symbol.
A common modern implementation for timing recovery is to have 2 to 4 samples per symbol, and then using fractional delay filters that operate at the same rate (such as polyphase filters or the Farrow Filter, which can be interpreted as a polyphase with LUT memory compression).  I provide more details in these approaches in my answer to DPS.SE #73645.

Is this answer also valid for FSK under low SNR?

Yes with the big assumption that the data has been filtered - otherwise with a higher sampling rate you can do that necessary filtering digitally. This is how the decimation process works- you can go from a higher sampling rate to a lower sampling rate with no consequence to the SNR as long as you have the necessary "anti-aliasing" filter first. Thus the number of samples per symbol (and how fast you sample in general) comes down to the spectral density of that signal + noise.  A properly designed receiver will ensure this before "4 samples/symbol" are created.
